# About Apache Rewrite Function to Shorten URL

Tags: apache

I have an URL "http://10.21.50.66:8123/test/file/index.htm" which hosted in Apache server. I would like to shorten the URL to just "http://10.21.50.66:8123/" and I managed to do it by using Rewrite function in httpd.conf. However, when I type "http://10.21.50.66:8123/" in browser, it will redirect and the URL of the browser will change back to the long url "http://10.21.50.66:8123/test/file/index.htm". What I would like to archive is that when every time I type "http://10.21.50.66:8123" in browser, the browser will open "http://10.21.50.66:8123/test/file/index.htm" but the URL on the browser will still showing "http://10.21.50.66:8123/". Below is the currecnt setting:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/$ http://10.21.50.66:8123/test/file/index.htm [R,L]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [R], the Apache will return response code 302 to the browser (with the new Location), which will cause that new URL to appear in address bar.

try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ /test/file/index.htm [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a **virtual host** in `httpd.conf`. You might find it in `extras` folder too as `httpd.vhosts.conf` Its something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@test.com
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

you need to write something like:

```
<VirtualHost 10.21.50.66:8123>
    ServerAdmin admin@test.com
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com
    DocumentRoot [path to your test/file folder] 
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```